# Problems serializing a c++\cli vector

Tags: xml-serialization, c++-cli

I am trying to serialize a vector of accounts but I keep getting the following exception :-

To be XML serializable, types which inherit from ICollection must have an implementation of Add(Account) at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy. cliext.vector does not implement Add(Account).

I have added an Add(Account) function to my class but it still doesn't work. I'm relatively new to C++ so my code is probably poor or might not be the correct way of doing what I want.

All help appreciated.

here is the main function :-

```
// TestDotNetXML.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Xml;
using namespace System::Xml::Serialization;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    AccountList^ MyAccountList = gcnew AccountList;
    Account^ Account1 = gcnew Account("1","1","1","1");    
    Account^ Account2 = gcnew Account("2","2","2","2");
    Account Account3;

    Account3.setAccountName("3");
    Account3.setUserName("3");
    Account3.setPassword("3");
    Account3.setDescription("3");

    MyAccountList->Add(Account1);
    MyAccountList->Add(Account2);
    MyAccountList->Add(Account3);


    try
    {
        XmlSerializer^ x = gcnew XmlSerializer(MyAccountList->GetType());
        x->Serialize(Console::Out, MyAccountList);
    }
    catch(System::InvalidOperationException^ ex)
    {
        Console::WriteLine(ex->InnerException);
    }

    Console::WriteLine();
    Console::ReadLine();

    return 0;
}
```

The Account class

Account.h

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
[Serializable]
public ref class Account
{
public:
    String^ accountName;
    String^ userName;
    String^ password;
    String^ description;
public:
    Account(String^ accountName, String^ userName, String^ password, String^ description);
    Account(void);
    Account(const Account% ob);
    Account% operator=(const Account% ob);
    ~Account(void);

    String^ getAccountName();
    void setAccountName(String^ accountName);
    String^ getUserName();
    void setUserName(String^ userName);
    String^ getPassword();
    void setPassword(String^ password);
    String^ getDescription();
    void setDescription(String^ description);

};
```

Account.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Account.h"


Account::Account(String^ accountName, String^ userName, String^ password, String^ description)
{
    this->accountName = gcnew String(accountName);
    this->userName = gcnew String(userName);
    this->password = gcnew String(password);
    this->description = gcnew String(description);
}

Account::Account(void)
{

}

Account::Account(const Account %ob)
{
    accountName = ob.accountName;
    userName = ob.userName;
    password = ob.password;
    description = ob.description;
}

Account% Account::operator=(const Account% ob)
{
    if(this != %ob)
    {
        accountName = ob.accountName;
        userName = ob.userName;
        password = ob.password;
        description = ob.description;
    }
    return *this;

}

Account::~Account(void)
{
    this->accountName = gcnew String("");
    this->userName = gcnew String("");
    this->password = gcnew String("");
    this->description = gcnew String("");
}

String^ Account::getAccountName()
{
    return this->accountName;
}
void Account::setAccountName(String^ accountName)
{
    this->accountName = accountName;
}

String^ Account::getUserName()
{
    return this->userName;
}
void Account::setUserName(String^ userName)
{
    this->userName = accountName;
}

String^ Account::getPassword()
{
    return this->password;
}
void Account::setPassword(String^ password)
{
    this->password = password;
}

String^ Account::getDescription()
{
    return this->description;
}
void Account::setDescription(String^ description)
{
    this->description = description;
}
```

AccountList.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cliext/vector>
#include "Account.h"

using namespace cliext;
public ref class AccountList
{
public:
    vector<Account^>^ List;
public:
    AccountList(void);
    void Add(Account^ anAccount);
    void Add(Account anAccount);
    void Remove(Account^ anAccount);
    bool Exists(Account^ anAccount);
    Account^ getAccout(String^ accountName);
    vector<Account^>^ getList(void);
    unsigned int stopLNK2022() { return List->size(); }
};
```

AccountList.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "AccountList.h"
#include "Account.h"

AccountList::AccountList(void)
{
    List = gcnew vector<Account^>;
}

void AccountList::Add(Account^ anAccount)
{
    this->List->push_back(anAccount);
}

void AccountList::Add(Account anAccount)
{
    Account^ ptrAccount = gcnew Account(
        anAccount.getAccountName(),
        anAccount.getUserName(),
        anAccount.getPassword(),
        anAccount.getDescription()
    );
    this->List->push_back(ptrAccount);
}

void AccountList::Remove(Account^ anAccount)
{
    vector<Account^>::iterator Iter;

    for(Iter = List->begin(); Iter != List->end(); Iter++)
    {
        if((safe_cast<Account^>(*Iter))->getAccountName()
            == anAccount->getAccountName())
        {
            List->erase(Iter);
        }
    }

}

bool AccountList::Exists(Account^ anAccount)
{
    vector<Account^>::iterator Iter;

    for(Iter = List->begin(); Iter != List->end(); Iter++)
    {
        if((safe_cast<Account^>(*Iter))->getAccountName()
            == anAccount->getAccountName())
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}

vector<Account^>^ AccountList::getList(void)
{
    return List;
}

Account^ AccountList::getAccout(String^ accountName)
{
    vector<Account^>::iterator Iter;

    for(Iter = List->begin(); Iter != List->end(); Iter++)
    {
        String^ test = (safe_cast<Account^>(*Iter))->getAccountName();
        if((safe_cast<Account^>(*Iter))->getAccountName()
            == accountName)
        {
            return safe_cast<Account^>(*Iter);
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: There are *lots* of reasons to not use STL/CLR, you just found another one.  [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24206/A-look-at-STL-CLR-performance-for-linear-container) demonstrates that well.  You'll need to get ahead by stopping to think in C++, managed code has significant advantages that do not translate into C++ at all.  Writing C++/CLI using C++ semantics gets you the worst of both.  Learning the C# language is a pretty good way to get there.

Comment: Indeed, you get the exception because `vector` has a `push_back` method instead of an `Add` method. You should use a managed collection, like `List<Account^>^`

Comment: That makes sense I assumed the error was in my classes not in the vector class. I will replace the AccountList with a managed collection and let you know what happens. Also for Hans the next step is c# I just wanted to finish my current project before I moved on. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Using a List works well thank you. How can I make that the answer ?